# How to access user data with Google Webmaster Tools API

Tags: php, google-api-php-client, google-search-console

I'm just starting to use the api libraries from google and I'm having some trouble accessing to user data. For experimentation I used code from a previos question in this field.
My code executes a petition for the google search console api but it returns an empty array. I autorized the service account from the admin console (https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount) so I don't know why doesn't it return anything.

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . '$path/google-api-php-client-master/src');
require_once realpath('$path/google-api-php-client-master/src/Google/autoload.php');

$client_id = "my-client-id"; 
$service_account_name = "my-service-account-name@developer.gserviceaccount.com"; 
$key_file_location = "privatekey.p12";

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("WMtools_application");
$service = new Google_Service_Webmasters($client);

if (isset($_SESSION['service_token'])) {
    $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['service_token']);
}
$key = file_get_contents($key_file_location);
$cred = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
    $service_account_name,
    array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webmasters.readonly'),
    $key
);
try{
    $client->setAssertionCredentials($cred);
    if ($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion($cred);
  }
    $_SESSION['service_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
}catch(Exception $e){
    echo "Exception captured",  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
try{
    $results = $service->sites->listSites();

    $siteList = $results->siteEntry;

    var_dump($siteList);
}catch(Exception $e2){
    echo "No results",  $e2->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem. The case is that i have delegated domain-wide authority to my service account and I didn't include in my petition to the API the user email from whom I want to access the data. To solve It just need to add it to the google_Auth_AssertionCredentials this way:

```
$cred = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
    $service_account_name,
    array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webmasters.readonly'),
    $key
);
$cred->sub = $service_account_user_email; //example@google.com
```